# Group records within a given time span

Tags: mysql, sql

say I have the following data:

```
id     value
uid1    20  
uid1    23  
uid1    30  
uid1    31  
uid1    32  
uid1    37  
uid1    39  
uid1    45  
uid2    33  
uid2    34
```

I want to group it so:

```
id      value
uid1    20,23
uid1    30,31,32,37,39
uid1    45
uid2    33,34
```

the logic is:
**group records with 'consecutive' values**.
**by consecutive I mean val1-val2 <= 5**

**5 is just an example I would like to solve it for any threshold I decide...**

in the example 30 & 39 are in the same group because they are part of a chain of numbers that differ in no more than 5.
Is there any way to achieve it in MySQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some simple arithmetic will do:

```
select id, group_concat(value order by value) as values
from t
group by id, floor(value / 10);
```

Or, if `value` is a string:

```
select id, group_concat(value order by value) as values
from t
group by id, left(value, 1);
```

Comment: indeed it works, for another threshold.. say 4.. will it work?

Comment: @belostoky . . . With the right second key on the `order by`, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's query seems to be working, but I would offer an alternative using session variables.  We can iterate over your table and check at each step whether a gap of 5 difference in the value occurs.  If it does, we form a new group, and we also reset the gaps when the `id` changes.

This may seem like overkill, but if the criteria for forming gaps and islands were more complex, then this approach might be more useful.

```
SET @gn = 0;
SET @id = NULL;
SET @value = NULL;
SET @threshold = 5;       -- or whatever value you want here

SELECT
    t.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.value ORDER BY t.value) AS value
FROM
(
    SELECT @gn:=CASE WHEN @id <> id THEN 0
                     WHEN value - @value > @threshold THEN @gn + 1
                     ELSE @gn END AS gn,
        @value:=value AS value,
        @id:=id AS id
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY id, value
) t
GROUP BY t.id, t.gn;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I never saw this kind of usage of variables, where can I read more about it?

Comment: @belostoky This is actually the most helpful site I have discovered so far: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/